# multiply number by itself PHP

Tags: php

How come the output of these two functions are not the same? Please enlighten me on this one.

first code:

```
function multiply_itself(&$number) {
    $number *= $number;
    return $number;
}
$my_num = 10;
echo "$my_num" . "<br>"; //Output 10

multiply_itself($my_num);
echo "$my_num"; //Outputs 100
```

second code:

```
function doubled($integer) {
    $integer *= $integer;
    return $integer;
}

$integer = 20;
doubled($integer);
echo "$integer"; //Outputs 20, why not 400?
```

Comment: You are not assigning the return value, and one of the two functions has a distinct parameter signature.

Comment: You are echoing the integer in the second example as opposed to the return value of the function but the first function directly changes  the variable as it is passed by reference. Excuse the short response, I am on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

The second example outputs `20` because the parameter is *not* passed by reference like in the first example.

Change the function signature to `function doubled(&$integer)` *or* use its return value `$integer = doubled($integer);` and it prints `400`.